# WTL and CContainedWindow causing access violation

Tags: c++, atl, wtl

I am trying to subclass a progress control in a dialog box using this code:

```
ATL::CContainedWindowT<WTL::CProgressBarCtrl> progress;
// ...
progress.SubclassWindow(GetDlgItem(IDC_PROGRESS));
```

All good there. Now if I try to do this:

```
progress.SetRange(0, 100);
```

I get access violation exception on `SendMessage` in a trivial WTL's `SetRange()` implementation. I have been searching up and down and all I could find was this could be some "thunking" issue as mentioned in [Applications Using Older ATL Components May Experience Conflicts With DEP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948468) which should not really apply to me because I am using the latest ATL and WTL (Visual Studio 2010 and [WTL 8.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/files/WTL%208.1/WTL%208.1.11324/)). I get the same issue even if I use WTL 8.0.

Subclassing was done OK as HWND is valid. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WTL::CProgressBarCtrl m_Progress; <~ use that to attach the progress bar, not CContainedWindow.

Comment: `CProgressBarCtrl` does not implement `SubclassWindow` so that's not the way to go. Can you be more specific?

Comment: m_Progress.Attach(GetDlgItem(IDC_PROGRESS1));
 m_Progress.SetPos(0);

Answer (score 2):

If you subclass a window, then you are expected to implement a message map for this subclassed control. This includes connecting your member variable to message map in constructor, adding [`ALT_MSG_MAP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d3ws24d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to the class message map. Are you doing this? I suppose you do not.

Do you need this in first place? To only send messages you don't need subclassing, you only need to attach real `HWND` to the `CProgressBarCtrl` instance:

```
WTL::CProgressBarCtrl m_ProgressBar;
// ...
m_ProgressBar = GetDlgItem(IDC_PROGRESS);
m_ProgressBar.SetRange(...
```

> Subclassing was done OK as HWND is valid

No, it was not OK. You hooked the window but you did not supply your WindowProc. Hence, the issue.

Comment: Thank you. The article from [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4028/WTL-for-MFC-Programmers-Part-IV-Dialogs-and-Contro) mislead me to believe I should use `CContainedWindow`. The article does use `ALT_MSG_MAP` but it wasn't obvious this was mandatory and the "access violation" was certainly a surprise. Even though your answer is far more elaborate, I am awarding @johnathon for being the first.

Comment: BTW The article does show the proper use of `CContainedWindow` in the "ATL Way 2" section http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4028/WTL-for-MFC-Programmers-Part-IV-Dialogs-and-Contro#atl2

Comment: Yes, I can see that now but the simple `m_ProgressBar = GetDlgItem(IDC_PROGRESS)` approach was not obvious. Thanks!